# TCP connection issue by using BlueSocket framework on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, sockets, tcp

Getting error of **"Error code: -9989(0x-2705), Connection refused"** by using BlueSocket framework and connecting between Mac and IOS.

Here is the logic:

**I am treating Mac as a server:**

```
// making TCP IPV4 socket
try self.listenSocket = Socket.create(family: .inet, type: .stream, proto: .tcp)

// start lisening port of 8888
try socket.listen(on: self.port)

// accept client connection when there is
let newSocket = try socket.acceptClientConnection()

// keep opening and reading data ....
```

**iPhone as a client:**

```
self.socket = try Socket.create(family: .inet)
try self.socket?.connect(to: ip, port: 8888)
try self.socket?.setReadTimeout(value: readWriteTimeOut)
try self.socket?.setWriteTimeout(value: readWriteTimeOut)
self.socket?.readBufferSize = Socket.SOCKET_MAXIMUM_SSL_READ_BUFFER_SIZE
```

1. client first time connect with the server works fine.
2. after the server receives data, client-side automatically closes the socket.
3. client tries to connect the server again to send back data by using same code above.
   Then error displays!

I think by default when the server-side uses `socket.listen`, it has `SO_REUSEADDR` set to `true`

Need suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to make sure while loop for `socket.acceptClientConnection()` is opening all the time....